# Asynchronous Client HTTP Transport Configuration

Tags: web-services, configuration, cxf, bus

I would like to set a custom value for some properties related to Asynchronous HTTP Transport such as the property `org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.SO_TIMEOUT`. My purpose is to configure it through a property file since I have to apply for different applications.

It is said in the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/Asynchronous+Client+HTTP+TransportAsyncHTTPConduitFactory) that options can be set using Bus properties or via the OSGi configuration services. However I cannot found any example.

Any clue how to do this?